# Lookup a pandas df for a column value by matching rows with another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Say I have a pandas dataframe `df1` as follows:

```
   OpDay    Rid     Tid    Sid   Dist
0  18Sep     1       1      1     10
1  18Sep     1       1      1     15
2  18Sep     1       1      1     20
3  18Sep     1       5      4     5
4  18Sep     1       5      4     50
```

and `df2` like:

```
   S_Day    R_ID     T_ID    S_ID   ABC    XYZ
0  18Sep     1        1       1     100    60
1  18Sep     1        5       4     125    100
```

Number of rows in `df2` is equal to total number of unique combinations of `OpDay+Rid+Tid+Sid` in `df1`.

Now, I want the values of `columns ABC and XYZ from df2` corresponding to this each unique combination. But I don't want to store these values in `df1`. Just need these values for some computation purpose and then I want to store the result in `df2` only by creating a new column.

To summarize, lets say ,I want to do some computation using `df1.Dist[3]` for which I need values from columns `df2.ABC` and `df2.XYZ` also, so first find the row index in `df2` where,

`S_Day = OpDay[3], 
R_ID = Rid[3], 
T_ID = Tid[3] and 
S_ID = Sid[3]`

(In this case its row#1), 
so use `df2.ABC[1]` and `df2.XYZ[1]` and store results in `df2.RESULT[1]`.

So now `df2` will look something like:

```
   S_Day    R_ID     T_ID    S_ID   ABC    XYZ          RESULT
0  18Sep     1        1       1     100    60             Nan
1  18Sep     1        5       4     125    100    some computed value
```

Basically I guess I need a lookup kind of a function but don't know how to proceed further.

Please help as I am new to the world of python and programming.  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .loc and Boolean indices to do what you want. Let's say that you're after the ith row of df1:

```
i = 3
```

Next, you can use Boolean indexing to find the corresponding rows in df2:

```
bool_index = (df1.loc[i, 'OpDay'] == df2.loc[:, 'S_Day']) & (df1.loc[i, 'Rid'] == df2.loc[:, 'R_ID']) & (df1.loc[i, 'Tid'] == df2.loc[:, 'T_ID']) & (df1.loc[i, 'Sid'] == df2.loc[:, 'S_ID'])
```

You might want to include a check to verify that you found one and only one combination:
`sum(bool_index) == 1`

And finally, you can use the boolean index to call the right values from df2:

```
ABC_for_computation = df2.loc[bool_index, 'ABC']
XYZ_for_computation = df2.loc[bool_index, 'XYZ']
```

Note that I'm not too sure about the speed of this operation if you have large datasets. In my experience, if speed is affected you should switch to numpy arrays instead of dataframes, particularly when writing data into your dataframe.

Comment: `@Rens` I tried this solution but its giving me Keyerror:0. Is there any other way to approach this problem? Also how to write result in df2.result. I mean how to find the appropriate row index for it?

Comment: Writing the result in df2 is easy: df2.loc[bool_index, 'result_column'] = your-result

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: `@Rens` Could it be possible that I am getting Keyerror:0 because I am using your statement inside `for k, d in df1.groupby(['Tid', 'Sid'])`?? I am using Python3.7 and pandas 0.25.3

Comment: Maybe. Could you please provide a more elaborate and accurate copy of your code?

Comment: In your example, you didn't specify 'mark'. Specify the index of df1, and you should be good to go! Next time, it's easier to read the code if you edit your original question and add the code there (with the 'code' layout).